Agave Node syncing fine with mainnet but RPC at 8899 isn't available
I'm using the config from the agave docs
tar jxf solana-release-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.bz2
cd solana-release/
export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH

All initial port checks come in fine
[2024-12-17T08:18:40.966962672Z INFO  agave_validator] agave-validator 2.0.18 (src:f77014dc; feat:607245837, client:Agave)
[2024-12-17T08:18:40.966987606Z INFO  agave_validator] Starting validator with: ArgsOs {
        inner: [
            "agave-validator",
            "--identity",
            "/home/ubuntu/validator-keypair.json",
            "--ledger",
            "/home/ubuntu/solana/ledger",
            "--accounts",
            "/home/ubuntu/solana/accounts",
            "--rpc-bind-address",
            "0.0.0.0",
            "--rpc-port",
            "8899",
            "--dynamic-port-range",
            "8000-8020",
            "--entrypoint",
            "entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001",
            "--expected-genesis-hash",
            "5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d",
            "--no-voting",
            "--limit-ledger-size",
            "--accounts-db-skip-shrink",
            "--rpc-send-batch-size",
            "100",
            "--rpc-send-batch-ms",
            "100",
            "--full-rpc-api",
        ],
    }
[2024-12-17T08:18:40.967017383Z WARN  solana_perf] CUDA is disabled
[2024-12-17T08:18:40.967019849Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX detected
[2024-12-17T08:18:40.967020827Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX2 detected
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.099700474Z INFO  agave_validator] obtained shred-version 50093 from 34.83.231.102:8001
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.102618157Z INFO  agave_validator] Snapshot configuration: full snapshot interval: 25000 slots, incremental snapshot interval: 100 slots
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.104159139Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] metrics disabled: environment variable not found
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.104561658Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: os-config platform="unix/linux/x86_64"
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105336173Z INFO  solana_core::system_monitor_service]   net.core.rmem_max: recommended=134217728 current=134217728
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105339270Z WARN  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: os-config net.core.rmem_max=134217728i
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105348306Z INFO  solana_core::system_monitor_service]   net.core.rmem_default: recommended=134217728 current=134217728
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105351820Z WARN  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: os-config net.core.rmem_default=134217728i
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105354507Z INFO  solana_core::system_monitor_service]   net.core.wmem_max: recommended=134217728 current=134217728
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105357000Z WARN  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: os-config net.core.wmem_max=134217728i
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105359840Z INFO  solana_core::system_monitor_service]   net.core.wmem_default: recommended=134217728 current=134217728
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105362756Z WARN  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: os-config net.core.wmem_default=134217728i
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105365444Z INFO  solana_core::system_monitor_service]   vm.max_map_count: recommended=1000000 current=1048576
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105370537Z INFO  solana_core::system_monitor_service]   net.core.optmem_max: report-only --  current=131072
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105374184Z INFO  solana_core::system_monitor_service]   net.core.netdev_max_backlog: report-only --  current=1000
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105391330Z INFO  agave_validator] OS network limits test passed.
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105375630Z WARN  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: os-config vm.max_map_count=1048576i
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105402254Z WARN  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: os-config net.core.optmem_max=131072i
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105406357Z WARN  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: os-config net.core.netdev_max_backlog=1000i
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.105948570Z INFO  agave_validator] Contacting 34.83.231.102:8001 to determine the validator's public IP address
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.109431427Z INFO  agave_validator::admin_rpc_service] started admin rpc service!
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.241143391Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] host id: BFZq1PTSAanwtyUNjJinm9v7JN5q2cJK8dKVzrSfvNQJ
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.243731343Z INFO  solana_entry::entry] Loading "libpoh-simd.so"
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.244277511Z WARN  solana_perf::perf_libs] "/usr/local/bin/perf-libs" does not exist
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.245415882Z INFO  solana_net_utils] Checking that tcp ports [(8899, TcpListener { addr: 0.0.0.0:8899, fd: 83 }), (8900, TcpListener { addr: 0.0.0.0:8900, fd: 84 }), (8000, TcpListener { addr: 0.0.0.0:8000, fd: 85 })] are reachable from 34.83.231.102:8001
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.567185237Z INFO  solana_net_utils] tcp/8899 is reachable
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.567444741Z INFO  solana_net_utils] tcp/8900 is reachable
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.567692081Z INFO  solana_net_utils] tcp/8000 is reachable
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.567803533Z INFO  solana_net_utils] Checking that udp ports [8000, 8001, 8003, 8004, 8005, 8006, 8007, 8008, 8009, 8010, 8012] are reachable from 34.83.231.102:8001
[2024-12-17T08:18:41.953723760Z INFO  solana_net_utils] checked udp ports: [8000, 8001, 8003, 8004], reachable udp ports: {8003, 8004, 8000, 8001}
[2024-12-17T08:18:42.337233451Z INFO  solana_net_utils] checked udp ports: [8005, 8006, 8007, 8008], reachable udp ports: {8005, 8007, 8008, 8006}
[2024-12-17T08:18:42.721075321Z INFO  solana_net_utils] checked udp ports: [8009, 8010, 8012], reachable udp ports: {8010, 8012, 8009}
[2024-12-17T08:18:43.732558495Z INFO  agave_validator::bootstrap] 

I was able to get my node RPC working on the old client, but when using agave the RPC is unavailable even once the snapshot is caught up and processed.
Any ideas on why port 8899 on localhost is unresponsive, i want to ask for the slot its on but it wont respond, on the old client even if not synced it would tell me where its up to..
Specs of m5.metal in AWS
Specification   Details
vCPUs   96 (Intel Xeon Platinum 8175M CPUs)
Architecture    x86_64
Processor   2nd Generation Intel Xeon Scalable
Clock Speed 2.5 GHz (Turbo up to 3.1 GHz)
RAM (Memory)    384 GiB
Storage EBS-Only (Elastic Block Storage)
Network Bandwidth   Up to 25 Gbps
EBS Bandwidth   14 Gbps
Max ENI Attachments 15
Placement   Bare Metal
Hypervisor  None (Bare Metal Instance)


Im using metal in AWS

Specs of m5.metal in AWS
Specification Details
vCPUs 96 (Intel Xeon Platinum 8175M CPUs)
Architecture x86_64
Processor 2nd Generation Intel Xeon Scalable
Clock Speed 2.5 GHz (Turbo up to 3.1 GHz)
RAM (Memory) 384 GiB
Storage EBS-Only (Elastic Block Storage)
Network Bandwidth Up to 25 Gbps
EBS Bandwidth 14 Gbps
Max ENI Attachments 15
Placement Bare Metal
Hypervisor None (Bare Metal Instance)
